# Why I'm getting different BigDecimal rounding results?

Tags: java, rounding

Why I'm getting following output:

**1.11**

1.13

when run below code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    double aDouble = 1.115;
    double bDouble = 1.125;

    System.out.println(roundTo2Decimal(aDouble));
    System.out.println(roundTo2Decimal(bDouble));
}

public static BigDecimal roundTo2Decimal(double doubleToRound){
    BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(doubleToRound);
    return bigDecimal.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
}
```

instead of expected result:

**1.12**

1.13 ?

Comment: The general lesson here is that if you care about decimal digits ever, you should never even _touch_ `double`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure this is just standard floating point imprecision. 0.125 = 1/8 which is exactly expressible in binary. 0.115 isn't so it's not stored exactly, and, apparently, is stored as something that rounds away from what you expect. Try `System.out.println` the double itself.

Comment: Thanks. I found some info about fp inaccuracy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples

Answer (score 2):

This occurs due to precision loss when representing 1.115 as double:

```
1.115 = 1.114999999999999991118215803E0
1.125 = 1.125E0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<code>
//to achieve what u need change your method to
    public static BigDecimal roundTo2Decimal(double doubleToRound) {
        BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(doubleToRound);
        return bigDecimal.setScale(2, RoundingMode.CEILING);
    }

</code>
```

Comment: Although this may provide the author with the desired results, it does not answer the question that was asked and should probably be a comment instead - such as: "*Instead of `BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP`, use `RoundingMode.CEILING`*".

Comment: But for 1.11400 and 1.12400 I need 1.11 and 1.12 accordingly. RoundingMode.CEILING don't give these results.